# EF 4.0 Lazy loading relationship during materialization

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a class like this

```
public class Definition
{
    public virtual string Name {} ..
    public void Validate(string value){}
}

public class Value
{
   private string innerValue;

   public virtual Definition Definition {}
   public string Value 
   {
      get {
         return innerValue;
       }
      set 
       {
         this.Definition.Validate(value);
         innerValue = value;
       }
    }
}
```

I am using Lazy loading, POCO, problem is when Value object is being materialized, EF does not try to load the Definition object ( which should load on lazy loading)

Do i need to do something special for it to work transparently ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy loading is not triggered during materialization.

Comment: is this a design flaw or a conscious choice ?

Comment: sounds more like a design flaw :)

Comment: and i could not find any documentation that says that either